# Does Google Bigquery support customer supplied encryption keys?

Tags: security, encryption, google-bigquery

BigQuery claims encryption at-rest support since Google encrypts data in its data centers[1] but apparently this encryption is done using Google's own keys.

Does BigQuery support customer-provided keys for at-rest data encryption?

[1] https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2014/08/googles-cloud-is-secure-but-you-dont.html

Comment: You may wish to check out the experimental [encrypted BigQuery client](https://github.com/google/encrypted-bigquery-client).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, BigQuery provides support for customer supplied encryption keys using the Google Cloud Console[1] and there is also experimental support for encryption keys using encrypted BigQuery client[2]. There is a broader range of capabilities that support customer supplied encryption keys in Google Cloud Storage and Google Compute Engine[3]

[1] https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-dlv9wJheF8&

[2] https://github.com/google/encrypted-bigquery-client

[3] https://cloud.google.com/security/encryption-at-rest/

Comment: Check also the announcement
https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/12/focus-on-security-bigquery-announces-support-for-customer-managed-encryption-keys-and-custom-roles-for-identity-access-and-management

Comment: @FelipeHoffa Isn't there a difference between "customer-supplied" and "customer-managed" keys? Customer-supplied, for me at least, is bring your own key(s). I thought BigQuery only supported "customer-managed" keys i.e. keys created by Cloud KMS. Maybe I'm confused :-/

Comment: Thanks for confirming @FelipeHoffa!

Comment: answer should be updated to indicate that CSEK is NOT supported but the next best thing available is CMEK